# How to wrtie the following command in userdata cloudformation?

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

not getting the value from find in map

```
UserData: !Base64 
        'Fn::Join':
          - |+

          - - '#!/bin/bash'
           - !Sub sudo -u $SPLUNK_USER $SPLUNK_BIN init shcluster-config
              -mgmt_uri https://$LOCALIP:8089 -replication_port 8090 -replication_factor !FindInMap[SplunkConfig, shcluster-replication-factor, num]
              -conf_deploy_fetch_url https://${SplunkSHCDeployer.PrivateIp}:8089 -shcluster_label SplunkSHC
              -secret ${SplunkClusterSecret} -auth admin:${SplunkAdminPassword}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be much better off using `Sub` instead of `Join`.

For `!FindInMap[SplunkConfig, shcluster-replication-factor, num]`, you'll need to specify it as a parameter to `Sub`.

You'll probably have something like:

```
  UserData: !Base64 
    'Fn::Sub':
      - |
        Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==BOUNDARY=="
        MIME-Version: 1.0
        --==BOUNDARY==
        Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

        #!/bin/bash
        sudo -u $SPLUNK_USER $SPLUNK_BIN init shcluster-config -mgmt_uri https://$LOCALIP:8089 -replication_port 8090 -replication_factor ${ReplicationFactor} -conf_deploy_fetch_url https://${SplunkSHCDeployer.PrivateIp}:8089 -shcluster_label SplunkSHC -secret ${SplunkClusterSecret} -auth admin:${SplunkAdminPassword}
        --==BOUNDARY==--

      - ReplicationFactor: !FindInMap[SplunkConfig, shcluster-replication-factor, num]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UserData: !Base64 
    'Fn::Join':
      - |+
      - - '#!/bin/bash'
        - !Join
        - - export $a= 
          - !FindInMap[SplunkConfig, shcluster-replication-factor, num]

       - !Sub sudo -u $SPLUNK_USER $SPLUNK_BIN init shcluster-config
          -mgmt_uri https://$LOCALIP:8089 -replication_port 8090 -replication_factor $a
          -conf_deploy_fetch_url https://${SplunkSHCDeployer.PrivateIp}:8089 -shcluster_label SplunkSHC
          -secret ${SplunkClusterSecret} -auth admin:${SplunkAdminPassword}
```

That worked for me.